# How to make C# winform application portable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, portable-executable, portable-applications

I have developed a winform application with C# 4.5. I want to make it portable. I meant that it should not need to be installed. To deploy this application I would like to just copy and paste the folder of application file. Like Tally or VLC Media player.

The environment and dependencies are as follows

C# Winform

.Net Framework 4.5

SQLite

Microsoft Report Viewer

Please suggest a way how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to simply copy the executable and necessary files?

Comment: *Did* you try to see if it needs any dependencies, eg just copy the binaries from bin/Debug or bin/Release it to another machine? XCopy deployment was one of the main features of .NET back in 2002.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of your project's references, you should verify *Copy Local* property is set to *True*. This way, all the references will be copied in your project's *bin* folder (at compile time).

This should be suficient for a copy/paste deployment of your *bin* folder.

Keep in mind,

> no program is an island -- Don Box

so deployment machines should need at least target framework installed.

.NET Framework will first search inside *bin* folder and if reference is not found, it will search the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I did this and it is working for now. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0):

XCopy deployment can be used to deploy your application.

Comment: Just make sure to use "CopyLocal" for all 3rd party assemblies to ensure they're part of the compilation output.